# Page break in Adobe LiveCycle with flowable content

Tags: adobe, livecycle-designer

It's the first time working with Adobe LiveCycle Designer.

I have a long pdf template.

I'd like to insert a page break between two section.
I don't find the right tool or option for this.
So I tried to split the layout in two pages.
So at this moment the template is made of two flowable pages.
Since the two pages have object->content->flowed, in the designer and when I generate the Preview PDF I continue to see the the first element of the "second page of the template" just next the last element of the "first page of the template", not in a second pdf page with the break.

To explain better:

[image]

This is the basic template structure at this time is:

[image]

I cannot find any explanation of how to this in LiveCycle section of Adobe Help: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/11.0/DesignerHelp/index.html

Any idea, explanation, or workaround is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this option,

1. In the structure of template "Hierarchy select the second page.
2. In "Object" palette select "Pagination" tab.
3. In "Place" setting change "Following previous" to "Top fo Page *****"

It seems to work in design and preview.